# Neural Network Implementation to forecast future behaviour can't detect sudden peaks

Tags: neural-network, time-series, prediction

Neural Network to predict future behaviour of a Time Series. My only feature is based on work load which is in between [0-100].

I am using (Backward Learning). As a output for example I am giving the 18 point ahead value and as input I gave the  latest 5 point to train.(I tried the many combinations of input data 5,10, 20 ,30...).

For example, the way I trained my data:
t,    t+1,  t+2, t+3, t+4...               =>  t+22(4+18)

```
                           t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4, t+5.. =>  t+23
```

Exponential inputs:
                                 t,    t+1,  t+2, t+4, t+8...     =>  t+26(8+18)

```
                           t+1, t+2, t+3, t+8, t+9...=>  t+27
```

After I trained, I have done forward learning with the my trained values. I have observed that neural network won't able to catch the sudden peaks. Most of the time if I am going to predict 18 seconds ahead, it predicts the correct result 17 seconds later.

> Do you have any advice for me about how could I able to predict sudden peaks(that will happen t seconds later) with neural network? or should I implement some other solution(like Ada Boost) to fix this situation?

Example of late prediction. At line 18 it was able to make the correct prediction because it finally reached the peaked value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks aren't magical. They just allow you to make associations of inputs and outputs based on a trained data set. If you train it with noisy data, your model will be noisy. If you de-emphasize noisy data in its learned model, it won't be able to predict noisy data.

The stock market and other industries are still unknown because it's hard to build a model through all the noise. Eliminate the noise and you essentially have a moving average, which will tend to predict values close to your previous observed values, not the sudden peaks you were hoping for.